# Does gradle project with dependency to another project get libraries?

Tags: java, gradle, classpath, gradlew, buildpath

I have two projects:

ProjectA makes use of ProjectB

ProjectA:

-- Settings.graddle:

```
include ':projectB'
```

-- build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':projectB')
}
```

ProjectB:

-- build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.modelmapper.extensions', name: 'modelmapper-jackson', version: '1.1.1'
}
```

This imports into ProjectB the modelmapper-jackson lib. (Expected behaviour)

It **also** imports modelmapper-jackson lib into **ProjectA**.

It might be this is the behaviour I want, **but**:

I would like to understand how to define what it is imported and what it is not, since in the future I might have more projects, and do not want all of them to have all the libraries

Is there anything in gradle I missed?

Comment: You can use `gradle dependencies` to inspect the dependency graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gradle dependencies` to inspect your dependency graph.

There are multiple approaches to stop transitive dependencies.

**Set dependency to compileOnly in project B***

`compileOnly group: 'org.modelmapper.extensions', name: 'modelmapper-jackson', version: '1.1.1'`

**Exclude in project A**

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':projectB') {
    exclude module 'modelmapper-jackson'
}
```